# 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all

Tags: django, django-views

Now, i have problem w M2O relectionship :(

Model.py

```
 class StorageDoc(models.Model):  # tabela dokumentująca ruch na magazynie
        typeList = (
            (' ', " "),
            ('WZ', "WZ"),
            ('PZ', "PZ"),
            ('PM', "PM")
        )
        docType = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=typeList, default=' ')
        storageName = models.ForeignKey(DictStorage, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        createTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        orderNumber = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)

class StorageDocPosition(models.Model):
                    storageDoc = models.ForeignKey(StorageDoc, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="sds")  
                    item = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
                    volumeUsed = models.IntegerField()
                    volumeBefore = models.IntegerField()
                    volumeAfter = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py

```
def StorageDocList (request):
    s_documents = StorageDocPosition.objects.all().prefetch_related("storageDoc")
    for s_document in s_documents:
        s_documentP = StorageDocPosition.storageDoc.all()

    return render(request, 'StorageDocList.html', {'storageDocAll': s_documents})

my error is:

    'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'
```

why I can not use "all" in this case?

How fix it?

Thanks for help :

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't quiet understant what you're trying to do with this `for` loop:

```
for s_document in s_documents:
    s_documentP = StorageDocPosition.storageDoc.all()
```

Besides the typo in s_document, you won't change the variable, you're just modifying a temporary iterator, the original s_document will still be the same, and you'd me passing in the context the same as the first line in the `SotrageDocList` function.

If what you're trying to achieve is getting all the prefetch related documents, just eliminate the `for` loop and pass a queryset into the context.

Hope this helped!